# NoMethodError - undefined method 'where' for User:Class in aws-sdk for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB. I am using aws-sdk for ruby as ORM and I the following error when I try to execute `User.where('name'=>'Joe')` or `User.all(:where => {:name => 'Joe'})`. Is this supported with aws-sdk or is there any other way to achieve this. My model looks like

```
class User < AWS::Record::HashModel
  string_attr :name
end
```

Thanks.

---

Error log:

Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-10 09:46:39 -0400
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `'where' for User:Class):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:6:in`index'

Answer (score 1):

It seems HashModel is incomplete and where is only supported by AWS::Record::Model (SimpleDB).

The easiest way around I found is to fallback to the dynamo_db_table object.

For arbitrary parameters, using SCAN:

```
User.dynamo_db_table.items.where(name: 'Joe').select('id', 'surname').map(&:attributes)
User.dynamo_db_table.items.where(name: 'Joe', birthday: ('2014-04-10'..'2014-04-17')).select(*User.attributes.keys).map(&:attributes)
User.dynamo_db_table.items.where(name: 'Joe', birthday: ('2014-04-10'..'2014-04-17')).select(*User.attributes.keys, limit: 1).map(&:attributes)
```

For querying by hash_key, using QUERY:

```
User.dynamo_db_table.items.query(hash_value: 'Joe', select: User.attributes.keys).map(&:attributes)
User.dynamo_db_table.items.query(hash_value: 'Joe', select: User.attributes.keys, limit: 1).map(&:attributes)
User.dynamo_db_table.items.query(hash_value: 'Joe', select: User.attributes.keys, limit: 1, scan_index_forward: false).map(&:attributes)
User.dynamo_db_table.items.query(hash_value: 'Joe', range_value: '2014-04-10'..'2014-04-17', select: [:birthday], limit: 1, scan_index_forward: false).map(&:attributes)
```

More information here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/ItemCollection.html#query-instance_method

Comment: You are correct. The HashModel is incomplete. I did write the api for 'where' for my work. I did use the query from ItemCollection, it worked. Thanks makhan

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, `User` class doesn't have a class method named `where` present in it or in any of its ancestors.

Instead use `User.all(:where => { :name => 'Joe' })`.

Refer to the Documentation of **[AWS::Record::HashModel Class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/Record/HashModel.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I did follow the documentation you mentioned and did try User.all(:where => { :name => 'Joe' }). I get the same error.

Comment: You get the exact same error? undefined method `where`? or you get undefined method `all`? Let me know or add the error log in the question.

Comment: I get the error "undefined method where". I have added the error log to the question.